# USB stick with hidden capacity?

Tags: dd, fdisk

While using `dd` on my USB drive, the USB drive accidentally got unplugged. The max capacity is 8GB, and 5GB had been written to it.

Now, when I try to reformat the USB drive or even remove all partitions and remake them (via `fdisk`), I see that all new partitions are being created with a maximum capacity of 3GB.

Is there something I can do to fix this? Simply removing all partitions seems to be Google's advice, but that is something I have done already.

Comment: Have you recreated the partition table?

Comment: Partition Tables hold Partition data. There are multiple kinds of Partition Tables; GPT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , MBR  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PT , BSD disklabel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_disklabel , and APM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Partition_Map (unlikely). The Gparted https://gparted.org/ GUI app makes changing these the easiest in Linux; the Windows app diskpart https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/how-to-diskpart-eraseclean-a-drive-through-the-command-prompt-005929en/ also does a decent job.